# How can i transform a stored procedure into a single SQL statment

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database which looks like (there can be same tuples in table):

```
+-------------+---------+--------+
| ProductName | Status  | Branch |
+-------------+---------+--------+
| P1          | dead    |      1 |
| P1          | dead    |      2 |
| P1          | dead    |      2 |
| P2          | expired |      1 |
+-------------+---------+--------+
```

I had to show the result after as (the Branch attribute is dynamic):

```
+-------------+---------+--------+
| ProductName | Branch 1|Branch 2|
+-------------+---------+--------+
| P1          | dead    |    dead|
| P2          | expired |     OK |
+-------------+---------+--------+
```

After some help i came up with following solution:

```
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
       CONCAT(
       'COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT case when branch = ''',
       branch,
       ''' then  status  end),''OK'') AS ',
       CONCAT('Branch',branch)
       )
    ) INTO @sql
    FROM Table1;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT productName, ', @sql, ' 
    FROM Table1 
    GROUP BY productName');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
```

It shows the exact result which i needed:

```
+-------------+---------+-----------+
| productName | Branch1 |  Branch2  |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
| p1          | dead    |    dead   |
| p2          | expired |    OK     |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ca97/89).

I want this procedure to be transformed into a single SQL statement. I have tried but couldn't find a solution. How can i achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Could we consider the `call spName(...)` a single statement?

Answer (score 0):

This exact result (as it's produced by the stored procedure, with the number of columns determined at runtime), cannot be reproduced in a single SQL select statement. It's not possible.